# Ektron: Getting content by folder ID - get all smartforms in folder?

Tags: c#, forms, directory, ektron

I'm new to Ektron, and I'm having trouble finding decent documentation on how to get content. I have a folder that contains smartforms. In my code, I need to get all those smartforms. This is all I have so far:

```
var folderManager = new FolderManager();
var folder = folderManager.GetTree(Convert.ToInt64(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AlumniSlideshowFolderId"]));
```

But from there, I have no idea how to get my data. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick.  You'll actually want to use the `ContentManager` instead of the `FolderManager`.  The criteria object is pretty powerful... you can refine the list down further if you need to.

```cs
var contentManager = new ContentManager();
int recordsPerPage;
int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AlumniSlideshow.RecordsPerPage"], out recordsPerPage);

int currentPage;
int.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["p"], out currentPage);
if (currentPage <= 0)
{
    currentPage = 1;
}

long alumniSlideshowFolderId;
long.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AlumniSlideshowFolderId"], out alumniSlideshowFolderId);

var criteria = new ContentCriteria();
criteria.AddFilter(ContentProperty.FolderId, CriteriaFilterOperator.EqualTo, alumniSlideshowFolderId);

// By default, the GetList method will use a 'recordsPerPage' value of 50.
criteria.PagingInfo = new PagingInfo(recordsPerPage, currentPage);
var content = contentManager.GetList(criteria);

foreach (var contentData in content)
{
    // work with each result here
}
```

You also mentioned not finding good documentation.  Here are a few links.  There is some pretty good documentation available, especially for the newer FrameworkAPI classes.  You just have to know where to look.

- http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/edr/web/edr.htm
- http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/edr/web/Content/FrameworkAPI/Content/ContentManager.htm

Comment: I am creating new content. I just want to check if a content already exists with the same title.

Comment: How can I check a collection and see what content exists with in?

Comment: Would be better if you had also provided the necessary using statements/namespaces that are required for this code to work: using Ektron.Cms.Framework.Content; using Ektron.Cms.Content; using Ektron.Cms.Common;